# Upgrade EE2 to EE3 : Internal Server Error

Tags: upgrade, ee2-upgrades

I have an EE 2.11.9 with only CE Image, Freeform, Stash, Deeploy Helper als Add-Ons that I want to Upgrade to EE 3.5.17.

I went forth and back several times, I even moved the site to a developer server as a copy where the same happens:

The site itself runs, but after typing the login information for the CP I get a Internal server error 500 on this template: /cp/login/authenticate.

The hosting provider has no clue nor have I one. I have checked a dozen of times and have had an EE fellow controlling if I was doing something wrong.

Can someone guide me into a direction where I might find a solution to this? I have spent now almost 2 days with this trouble.

Thank you.

Edit:

After setting debug to 1 in admin.php I get this error messages:

```
Notice
Trying to get property of non-object

ee/legacy/libraries/Session.php, line 369 hide details

    Severity: E_NOTICE

Notice
Trying to get property of non-object

ee/legacy/libraries/Session.php, line 369 show details

    Severity: E_NOTICE

Notice
Trying to get property of non-object

ee/legacy/libraries/Session.php, line 378 show details

    Severity: E_NOTICE

Notice
Trying to get property of non-object

ee/legacy/libraries/Session.php, line 401 show details

    Severity: E_NOTICE


Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null in /home/octave2d/public_html/_wernergusset/expconsole/ee/legacy/libraries/Session.php on line 401
```

Does this lead to some insights?

Comment: Does your EE2 site currently have any Add-ons that work with member records (such as User or Zoo Visitor)?

Comment: No, it does not. The Add-Os are mention at the beginning of my post.

Comment: I asked because a possible issue here is an incomplete member record. EE2 was not strict on member records being complete as a model but EE3/4/5 is much more strict in the code. Something that has worked for me on an upgrade run is to create a brand new `superadmin` account natively right before the upgrade run, and use that after. Then solve your member records inconsistencies in the database.

Comment: Thank you! I created a new superadmin (the initial registration was from April 2004 made on EE1). Then I deleted the old superadmin and an old testadmin. After that I started a new upgrade process. And bingo: I am on EE3! Now I can go on from here. Very helpful comment,  jrothafer. (do I need to write an answer?)

Comment: You don't, but I did :) I hope you accept my answer, and happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have an incomplete member record issue. EE2 was not very strict about the member model being complete; however, EE3/4/5 is much more strict and will hit fatal errors if a member record isn't complete (a member doesn't have a row in every database table they should have one in). I also believe the upgrade from EE1 to EE2 doesn't properly update member records, meaning old EE1 registered users will probably have incomplete member records especially if they've never updated their member in any way (preferences, date of birth, etc).

One of the easiest solutions is to just create a new Superadmin member, making sure to use the native member creation functionality and not any add-on's create-member functionality (such as Zoo Visitor or User). That should create a new and complete Superadmin member, and you should be able to log in after you upgrade with that new account.

If you have other users who also get this error when logging in to the Control Panel, this will be a similar issue. To work through this, you may have to look at all the member tables, and manually add rows for the `member_id`'s that don't have them where they should. This will avoid removing a content editor and having to deal with reassigning their Channel Entries to another author.

Comment: Is there any way to create a new superuser account via cli or db inserts? My member_id=1 account is broken, so I have no way to access the web frontend without rolling back to ee2.

Comment: I have the same issue. Thank you man
This post has been saved my time to solve the issue because I have added the user manually in the DB so then I have updated the password of the existing member and log in with that admin login working fine in the EE3

Answer (score 0):

Did you move your index.php and admin.php from the old install or did you use the new index.php and admin? If you kept the old it might be setting your cp link to the wrong place. Try moving the new index.php and admin.php into the root directory.

Comment: Yes, I used the new index,php and admin.php in the root directory.